# cual es tipo de campo correcto para dni mysql

Tags: php, mysql

- Cual es tipo de campo correcto para guardar un dni o numero de identidad nacional en una base de datos ? *

Comment: Considera leer [ask] pues esta es una pregunta basada en opiniones y por lo mismo terminaría cerrada

Answer (score 1):

char(8) puesto que si intentas guardar con int y el numero empieza en 0 se elimina los 0 a la izquierda, mejor un char(8)